# how to optimize a long query mysql

Tags: mysql

How to optimze this query mysql :

```
SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE caption LIKE @query OR owner LIKE @query AND roomtype = 'private' ORDER BY users_now DESC LIMIT 50
```

This is my code:

```
internal ServerMessage SerializeSearchResults(string SearchQuery)
{
    DataTable Data = new DataTable();

    using (IQueryAdapter dbClient = PlusEnvironment.GetDatabaseManager().getQueryreactor())
    {
        if (SearchQuery.Length > 0)
        {
            if (SearchQuery.ToLower().StartsWith("owner:"))
            {
                dbClient.setQuery("SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE owner = @query AND roomtype = 'private' ORDER BY users_now DESC LIMIT 50");
                dbClient.addParameter("query", SearchQuery.Remove(0, 6));
            }
            else
            {
                dbClient.setQuery("SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE caption LIKE @query OR owner LIKE @query AND roomtype = 'private' ORDER BY users_now DESC LIMIT 50");
                dbClient.addParameter("query", "%" + SearchQuery + "%");
            }
            Data = dbClient.getTable();
        }
    }

    List<RoomData> Results = new List<RoomData>();

    if (Data != null)
    {
        foreach (DataRow Row in Data.Rows)
        {
            RoomData RData = PlusEnvironment.GetGame().GetRoomManager().FetchRoomData(Convert.ToUInt32(Row["id"]), Row);
            Results.Add(RData);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your SQL query doesn't look particularly complex

Comment: why you tagged this with c#,c and php ?

Comment: Start by running an EXPLAIN against the query

Comment: If you're having performance issues start by checking how you're indexing before attempting to optimise such a mundane query.

Comment: Are you sure your performance issues are with the query, and not with the processing of the result? What does `FetchRoomData()` do for example?

Comment: Provide your database table with some sample data. Also give your expected result. We'll provide you the correct query

Comment: @EugenHalca: Smells like C#. Question is why it tagged with "Java"

Comment: @user1538524: Avoid `LIKE` in SQL queries. Likely causes an full table scan and makes indexes useless. Either think if you can normalize your table design; or use a fulltext search engine (like Lucene)

Comment: 1 SIMPLE rooms index  users_now 4  50 Using where

Comment: This is not java, so no need to tag it with java

Answer (score 1):

The best way to optimize the performance of the query is to add indexes to the fields that you are using more frequently in your where clauses. For example, in MySQL you can add an index like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `rooms` ADD INDEX `owner` (`owner`)
```

Answer (score 1):

The query doesn't look particularly complicate so you might try adding an index by roomtype and users_now to speed up SELECT.

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON rooms (roomtype ASC, users_now DESC)
```

Also try to limit the usage of `LIKE` in a query as it severely affects performance.

Comment: i get this error:#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NONCLUSTERED INDEX index_name ON rooms (roomtype ASC, users_now DESC) INCLUDE (' at line 1

Comment: @user1538524 Forgot that in mysql you can't include aditional columns in the index. I edited the script. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html